# Execute dynamic code

Tags: javascript

i have following in a string.

```
javascript: __doPostBack('GridWidget', 'Edit$0')
```

how can i dynamically execute this?

Comment: Lets me wonder: where does this string come from? Can't you include this in a static JS file? If it's really dynamic (e.g., user input), you're creating a **huge** security hole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the "javascript:" from the front, and call eval() on the string.

Answer (score 0):

```
var js = "javascript: __doPostBack('GridWidget', 'Edit$0')".replace("javascript:","");
eval(js)
```